# Create AutoMapper in Test Project (including AutoMapper.Profile classes)

Tags: automapper

I have a .net core service api which uses AutoMapper, and in Startup::ConfigureServices the services collection uses the AddAutoMapper extension to perform all the initialization necessary for dependency injection of an IMapper interface, e.g. services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));  The way I understand it is that by doing this, scanning is done for any/all AutoMapper.Profile types in order to set up the IMapper for DI into other constructors.  Works great.

Now I'm writing tests for the service, and am wondering how to create this IMapper outside of Startup?  Mocking it seems pointless, I just want to use it, so how do I create an instance of what I need that utilizes all of the AutoMapper.Profiles I have set up?

Comment: You can use `AddAutoMapper` in your tests too. After all you wanna be as close as possible to the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by simply creating a MapperConfiguration which points to the needed Profile classes:

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<TestProfile>());
IMapper _mapper = new Mapper(mapperConfig);
```